# Using a single intent to retrieve multiple records vs a separate intent for each record

Tags: android, android-intent, performance-testing

I am trying to assess the benefits and costs of using a single intent for a long process versus using up to five separate intents.

Users of my App download records from web which are parsed into databases. A user may download records for 1 to 5 people at any given time.

I had the App set up like this:

```
    private OnClickListener mySubmitOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       ArrayList<String> idsOfRecordsArray = getIdsOfRecordsToDownload();

               Intent intentToRetrieve = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                                  RetrieveData.class);
        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
        intentToRetrieve.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);

        intentToRetrieve.putStringArrayListExtra ("IdList",
                                                     idsOfRecordsArray);

        v.getContext().startService(intentToRetrieve);

        showDialog("Some Message");

        }
      }
```

This worked but because of the time required to parse the data, I would sometimes get timeout errors.

I changed it to this:

```
    private OnClickListener mySubmitOnClick = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       ArrayList<String> idsOfRecordsArray = getIdsOfRecordsToDownload();
               while(iCount < idsOfRecordsArray.size()) {
        ArrayList<String> currentID = new ArrayList<String>();

        currentAthleteID.add(athleteIdArray.get(iCountAthletes));
        Intent intentToRetrieve = new Intent(getActivity(),
                                              RetrieveData.class);
        Messenger messenger = new Messenger(handler);
        intentToRetrieve.putExtra("MESSENGER", messenger);

        intentToRetrieve.putStringArrayListExtra ("IdList",
                                                              currentID);

        v.getContext().startService(intentToRetrieve);

        showDialog("Some Message");

        iCount++;
        }
        }
```

So I can now have up to five (5) intents fired off at the same time. This seems stable, enough. However, handling the Progress Dialogs is a bit of a nuisance. If I only open 1 dialog box, it closes before the processes are complete.

Any thoughts on which is the better approach here? Or perhaps I should abandon both for some other method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do the work in the background, using an IntentService. You can fire off as many intents as you want, but the IntentService will only process one at a time. Meanwhile, you won't get timeouts and the user can continue to do work. I think users will accept that the results don't arrive immediately, as long as they can do something else while they're waiting.

See the Android training class [Running in a Background Service](http://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/index.html) as an example.